# Putting values from Textboxes into an array

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good Day,
I have created a simple form with three boxes to capture text data. I also have a button that duplicates the form to facilitate multiple entries. I want to be able to take that data and place into 3 arrays, one for each text box.

The code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#add").click(function()
            {
                addThis = "<div class='row mb-3'><div class='col-12'><input type='text' name='fname[]' id='fname' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name'></div></div><div class='row mb-3'><div class='col-12'><input type='text' name='mname[]' id='mname' class='form-control' placeholder='Middle Name'></div></div><div class='row mb-3'><div class='col-12'><input type='text' name='lname[]' id='lname' class='form-control' placeholder='Last Name'></div></div>";
             
                $("#form1").append(addThis);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" id="form2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="" id="form1" class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="mname[]" id="mname" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <input type="text" name="lname[]" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <form action="">
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add Another</button>
                        <button type="button" name="test" class="btn btn-success">TEST</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I want to eventually submit the data into the table, looping through the arrays for each instance of the form.
Could some one point me in the right direction please?

Comment: First, I would remove your IDs. This won't affect what you are trying to do, but you could run into problems as IDs must be unique on the page. Since the processing of the arrays would be done server side in PHP, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a possible solution using `fieldset`s to group your name inputs.

See comments in jQuery JS so you know whats happening...

```js
// our form as const object
const form = $('#form');

// on form submit pass event
$(form).on('submit', function(e) {

  // stop event default behaviour
  e.preventDefault();

  // set entry as serialized array
  let entry_arr_obj = $(this).serializeArray();

  // set empty object for formatted entry data
  let formatted_entry_obj = {};

  // for each entry array obj values as key => object
  $.each(entry_arr_obj, function(k, obj) {
  
    // split object field name by underscore to create name_fieldset array containing fieldset id and name key
    let name_fieldset = obj.name.split('_');
  
    // set the set id from name_fieldset array
    let fieldset = parseInt(name_fieldset[1]);
    
    // set name key from name_fieldset array
    let name = name_fieldset[0];
    
    // if formatted_entry_obj does not have own property matching current fieldset id
    if(!formatted_entry_obj.hasOwnProperty(fieldset)) {
  
      // add fieldset id and empty object to formatted_entry_obj
      formatted_entry_obj[fieldset] = {};
  
    }
  
    // add field name and field value to formatted_entry_obj current fieldset object
    formatted_entry_obj[fieldset][name] = obj.value;
  
  });

  // log our entry object
  console.log(formatted_entry_obj);

});

// on form add field set
$(form).on('click', '.add', function(e) {

  // get all our fieldsets
    let fieldsets = $('fieldset',form);
  
  // last fieldset obj and id
  let last_fieldset = fieldsets[fieldsets.length-1];
  let last_fieldset_id = parseInt($(last_fieldset).data('set'));
  
  // create new fieldset id
  let new_fieldset_id = last_fieldset_id + 1;
  
  // clone last fieldset and filter attributes
  $(last_fieldset).clone().filter(function() {
  
    // update data set attribute with new fieldset id
    $(this).attr(
        'data-set',
        new_fieldset_id
      
    // now filter children elements (cols) 
    ).children().filter(function() {
    
        // now filter children elements (inputs) 
        $(this).children().filter(function() {
        
          // get child element name attr 
          let name_attr = $(this).attr('name');

          // if we have name attr
          if(name_attr) {

            // explode the name attr value via underscore
            let name_fieldset = name_attr.split('_');

            // return updated name attribute with new fieldset name and empty value
            return $(this).attr(
              'name', 
              name_fieldset[0] + '_' + new_fieldset_id
            ).val(null);

          }

          // else return child element
          return $(this);
        
        });
        
        // return child element
        return $(this);
        
        });
      
    // return all of cloned elem   
    return $(this);
    
  // then insert after last field set  
    }).insertAfter(last_fieldset);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container py-3">
  <form id="form">
    <fieldset data-set="1" class="form-row mb-3">
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <input type="text" name="fname_1" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
       </div>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <input type="text" name="mname_1" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
       </div>  
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <input type="text" name="lname_1" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
       </div>  
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" class="add btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">Add Fieldset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```